# Serialize all the fields into one byte array and deserialize byte array into individual fields

Tags: java, array, serialization

I have a class in which I am passing certain parameters through the constructor and then using those parameters to make one final byte array with a proper format (header + data) and it works fine:

```
public final class Frame {
  private final byte addressedCenter;
  private final byte version;
  private final Map<byte[], byte[]> keyDataHolder;
  private final long location;
  private final long locationFrom;
  private final long locationOrigin;
  private final byte partition;
  private final byte copy;

  public Frame(byte addressedCenter, byte version,
      Map<byte[], byte[]> keyDataHolder, long location, long locationFrom,
      long locationOrigin, byte partition, byte copy) {
    this.addressedCenter = addressedCenter;
    this.version = version;
    this.keyDataHolder = keyDataHolder;
    this.location = location;
    this.locationFrom = locationFrom;
    this.locationOrigin = locationOrigin;
    this.partition = partition;
    this.copy = copy;
  }

  public byte[] serialize() {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(getBufferUsed(keyDataHolder)).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

    // header layout
    byteBuffer.put(addressedCenter).put(version).putInt(keyDataHolder.size())
        .putInt(getBufferUsed(keyDataHolder)).putLong(location).putLong(locationFrom)
        .putLong(locationOrigin).put(partition).put(copy);

    // now the data layout
    for (Map.Entry<byte[], byte[]> entry : keyDataHolder.entrySet()) {
      byte keyType = 0;
      byte[] key = entry.getKey();
      byte[] value = entry.getValue();
      byte keyLength = (byte) key.length;
      short valueLength = (short) value.length;

      ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(value);
      long timestamp = valueLength > 10 ? dataBuffer.getLong(2) : System.currentTimeMillis();

      byteBuffer.put(keyType).put(keyLength).put(key).putLong(timestamp).putShort(valueLength)
          .put(value);
    }

    return byteBuffer.array();
  }

  // this method is returning only `locationFrom`
  public static long getLocationFrom(final byte[] byteArray) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    bb.rewind();

    byte addressedCenter = bb.get();
    byte version = bb.get();
    int numOfRecords = bb.getInt();
    int bufferUsed = bb.getInt();
    long location = bb.getLong();
    long locationFrom = bb.getLong();
    long locationOrigin = bb.getLong();
    byte partition = bb.get();
    byte copy = bb.get();

    byte keyType = bb.get();
    byte keyLength = bb.get();
    byte[] extractKeyValue = new byte[keyLength];
    bb.get(extractKeyValue);
    String key = new String(extractKeyValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    long timestamp = bb.getLong();
    short dataSize = bb.getShort();

    if (dataSize >= 16) {
      location = bb.getLong();
      locationFrom = bb.getLong();
    } else {
        // log that we have different size and we cannot extract
        // location and locationFrom it.
    }
    return locationFrom;
  } 

  // this method is returning only `location`
  public static long getLocation(final byte[] byteArray) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    bb.rewind();

    byte addressedCenter = bb.get();
    byte version = bb.get();
    int numOfRecords = bb.getInt();
    int bufferUsed = bb.getInt();
    long location = bb.getLong();
    long locationFrom = bb.getLong();
    long locationOrigin = bb.getLong();
    byte partition = bb.get();
    byte copy = bb.get();

    byte keyType = bb.get();
    byte keyLength = bb.get();
    byte[] extractKeyValue = new byte[keyLength];
    bb.get(extractKeyValue);
    String key = new String(extractKeyValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    long timestamp = bb.getLong();
    short dataSize = bb.getShort();

    if (dataSize >= 16) {
      location = bb.getLong();
      locationFrom = bb.getLong();
    } else {
        // log that we have different size and we cannot extract
        // location and locationFrom it.
    }
    return location;
  }       

  // 36 + dataSize + 1 + 1 + keyLength + 8 + 2;
  private int getBufferUsed(final Map<byte[], byte[]> keyDataHolder) {
    int size = 36;
    for (Map.Entry<byte[], byte[]> entry : keyDataHolder.entrySet()) {
      size += 1 + 1 + 8 + 2;
      size += entry.getKey().length;
      size += entry.getValue().length;
    }
    return size;
  }  
}
```

**Question**

Now once I call `serialize()` method of above class, it will give me actual packed `byteArray`:

```
Frame frame = new Frame(......);
byte[] packedByteArray = frame.serialize();
// send packedByteArray to some other system
.......

byte[] byteArray = getFromOtherSystem();
long locationFrom = Frame.getLocationFrom(byteArray);
long location = Frame.getLocation(byteArray);
```

Now once I have this `packedByteArray`, I send it to some other system and then that system will return me back another `byteArray` which is packed in the same format as shown above in the `serialize` method. Now I need to use this `byteArray` and extract all the individual fields from it so I wrote the `getLocationFrom` method that takes the `byteArray` as the parameter and it will return me `locationFrom` field value only for now. When the other system sends me back the `byteArray`, its data size should be around 16 only and actual data will have two long values in it and data will always be in the same format when it comes from other system.

Right now my `getLocationFrom` method just returns `locationFrom` field only but if I want to get `location` or `locationOrigin` or `version` or other fields then should I add respective static methods in my `DataFrame` class? If I do that, then I will be repeating all the deserialization logic in all the static methods for each fields.

How should I design this `Frame` class so that it can take all the parameters to make one `packedByteArray` (through the constructor I am doing right now) and also it should be able to take `byteArray` parameter as well and give me all other fields by deserializing this? Just like I am doing for `locationFrom` field.

I am mainly trying to see how I can design my class so that if I asks for individual fields value given a `byteArray`, it should be able to give me those values back. Also, it should be able to serialize everything into one `byteArray` given all the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of shuffling the byte array around all the time, I'd rather create an additional Frame constructor, which operates on the byte array, performs the deserialization and sets all internal variables to the values from that byte array.

Then, you'd just parse the answer into an object and use the object for all later references:

```
byte[] byteArray = getFromOtherSystem();
Frame answerFrame = new Frame(byteArray);  // or a static factory method, or whatever
long locationFrom = answerFrame.locationFrom;
long location = answerFrame.location;
```

---

Trying to stick that constructor together after the comment:

```
public Frame(byte[] byteArray) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    bb.rewind();

    this.addressedCenter = bb.get();
    this.version = bb.get();
    this.numOfRecords = bb.getInt();
    this.bufferUsed = bb.getInt();
    this.location = bb.getLong();
    this.locationFrom = bb.getLong();
    this.locationOrigin = bb.getLong();
    this.partition = bb.get();
    this.copy = bb.get();

    this.keyDataHolder = new HashMap<>();
    // Add code here to deserialize the map contents and add them to the map
    // this goes too much into detail for me ;-)
}
```

As to your compilation error: when you are working with final fields, each class constructor *must* ensure, that *all* fields are initialized. This initialization of all fields is the main point of the answer: deserialize the complete buffer *once* and then take all further interaction with the answer frame back to object level.

Comment: If I create another `Frame` constructor that takes byte array parameter, then it asks me to initialize other final fields as well in the same constructor? Or I am missing something? Can you provide an example of this? Because I tried this and it gave me compilation error asking me to initialize all other fields which are final in the same  class.

Comment: See the edit for an answer.